# Open Viewcontroller from AppDelegate with Link

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have a small problem.

I try for a push notification to control a View Controller.

I come to go there, however, the new "page" not open. 
If I send forth the same but with an action button it works.

Thank you, Chris

**AppDelegate.m**

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
[rootViewController openLinkNews];
```

**RootViewController.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   self.contentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];
   self.menuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuController"];
} 

-(void)openLinkNews {
   NewsTab *theLink = [[NewsTab alloc] init];
   [theLink openNewsPerLink];    
}
```

**NewsTab.m**

```
-(void)openNewsPerLink{
   NSLog(@"You are here!");

   dbConnect = [[DbConnect alloc] init];
   getNewsLast = [dbConnect getNewsLast];
   DbConnect *news = [getNewsLast objectAtIndex:0];

   NewsTab * infoController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsOpenViewController"];
   NewsOpen *detailViewController = (NewsOpen *) infoController;
   detailViewController.NewsHeadline = news.NewsHeadline;
   detailViewController.NewsInformation = news.NewsInformation;
   detailViewController.NewsFrom = news.NewsFrom;
   detailViewController.NewsDate = news.NewsDate;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoController animated:YES];
}



-(IBAction)ButtonTest:(id)sender {
    [self openNewsPerLink];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted code from your app delegate, but what method is that in?

The app delegate can retrieve information about the notification and respond to it in its `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method. From there you you can do whatever you wish and use the notification to inform your decisions.

Please see the [UIApplicationDelegate protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveLocalNotification%3a)